# Windows Explorer hang restart timeout

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, freeze

I have a slow PC, and sometimes, when it's busy, explorer hangs for a couple of seconds. If the hang takes long enough, explorer restarts automatically.

Is there a setting to disable this behavior, or to change the delay? A registry tweak perhaps?

Comment: does Explorer crash (Stopped working)?

Comment: It doesn't crash, but is being restarted by the system. Event log shows: "Problem Event Name: AppHangB1"

Comment: so this is a hang. I see explroer hangs since win8 because of the windows defender